# string value is truncating when saved to the database

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate, and my classes property is a string, and my mapping doesn't have any type information, ie:

```
  <property name="html"  />
```

I am storing a web page in the html database column, and for some reason the entire page isn't saving, it gets cut off part way.

I outputed the value of the property to console and it does output all the way to the ending `</html>` tag.

Does hiberate truncate a string value?

**the database column is a nvarchar(max) (sql server)**

Turns out it was writing the entire string to the database, just copy and pasting from the database editor was truncating the actual text stored in the db column.

Comment: He stated that it's an nvarchar(max), and it's a string in his code.

Comment: i bolded it just for you - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<property name="Value" type="LongVarChar" />
```

Comment: always check whether your answer displays properly. You didn't format your code and your answer contained only "try".

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="html" length="20000" />
```

I.e. specify the length attribute and set it to a value big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<property name="Value" type="StringClob" />
```

Otherwise, Hibernate needs to know the length when dealing with large strings.